# Why is 0^1 = 1 in Python?

Tags: python, operators

I was looking at a problem solution in Python where the only number without a pair in an array is returned. The solution is below :

```
def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    if A is None or n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return A[0]
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        result ^= A[i]
    return result
```

How is the loop logic returning back the unique number?

Comment: `^` is not the power in Python.

Comment: BTW, the program will crash if `A` is `None` because you do `n = len(A)` before you check it with `if A is None`.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator in python is the XOR operator
and what it means is that for each a,b:

`a^b = a'b + b'a`

and in truth table it looks like this:

| a | b | a^b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |